# Hide folder from root URL of website

Tags: apache-2.2, web-hosting, drupal

I have a website set up on shared hosting like so...

http://www.mysite.com/cms/index.php

I'd like to have the /cms folder hidden from the URL. I also need to manage redirects from the old folder structure - if that is necessary.

Thanks

---

**Update**

I ended up using this:

`RewriteRule (.*) cms/$1 [L]` [from this doc](http://drupal.org/node/135206)

Added to settings.php for drupal

`$base_url = 'http://www.mysite.com;  // NO trailing slash!`

Now just need to fix the redirects - the original pages come up, but retain the rewritten folder.

Comment: Not an apache guru here but check into .htaccess files. I think those or simple permissions will achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to look into is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache (often part of the default install).

You will then rewrite your URLs. For example:

```
#rewrite http://www.mysite.com/index.php to http://www.mysite.com/cms/index.php
#add more rules or RewriteCond to account for old URLs you want to keep active.    
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  /cms/$1
```

You'll probably also want to do a search on drupal and pretty or clean urls which will give you more info on this and will also let you drop the index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable mod_rewrite and to add a rewrite rule like this:

`RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /cms/$1`

Not sure about redirects, probably you should utilize mod_proxy to handle proper redirects.

Comment: mod_rewrite can't handle this with something like this?   RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @Sam careful doing that, you could end up in a redirect loop.

Comment: @Sam You should try to put `RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` before `RewriteRule (.*) cms/$1 [L]`, it looks like it will work this way

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working - just leaves the url as is.  I'm using WAMP(local dev server) with localhost as the domain name.